# Default Value From Drop Down List

Tags: excel, excel-2003, vba

I wonder whether someone may be able to help me please.

I'm using the code below, which among a number of actions being performed, automatically populates column "A" with the date, and column "AS" with the text value "No" when a new record is created within a Excel spreadsheet.

```
Option Explicit
Public preValue As Variant
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

    Dim Cell As Range, res As Variant
    Dim rCell As Range
    Dim Rng1 As Range
    Dim Rng2 As Range
    Dim Rng3 As Range


    Application.EnableCancelKey = xlDisabled
    'Sheets("Input").Protect "handsoff", UserInterFaceOnly:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowFormattingColumns:=True

    If Target.Column = 3 Then
        If Target = "No" Then MsgBox "Please remember to make the same change to all rows for " & Target.Offset(0, -1).Value & " and delete any future forecasts"
    End If

       If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
    On Error Resume Next

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B5:AD400", "AF5:AQ400")) Is Nothing Then
        If Target.Value <> preValue And Target.Value <> "" Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
           With Rows(Target.Row)
                    .Range("A1").Value = Date
                    .Range("AS1").Value = "No"
        End With
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Target.Interior.ColorIndex = 35
        End If
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0
    If Target.Column = 45 Then
                If Target.Value = "Yes" Then
                Set Rng1 = Application.Union(Cells(Target.Row, "B").Resize(, 19), Cells(Target.Row, "R"))
                Rng1.Interior.ColorIndex = xlNone
                Set Rng2 = Application.Union(Cells(Target.Row, "S").Resize(, 12), Cells(Target.Row, "AD"))
                Rng2.Interior.ColorIndex = 37
                Set Rng3 = Application.Union(Cells(Target.Row, "AF").Resize(, 12), Cells(Target.Row, "AQ"))
                Rng3.Interior.ColorIndex = 42
                End If
    End If

    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("J7:J400")) Is Nothing Then
        Set Cell = Worksheets("Lists").Range("B2:C23")
        res = Application.VLookup(Target, Cell, 2, False)
    If IsError(res) Then
        Range("K" & Target.Row).Value = ""
    Else
        Range("K" & Target.Row).Value = res
    End If
    End If

End Sub
```

What I'd like to do, if at all possible, is when the date is inserted into column "A", I'd like to insert the text value "Select" on the same row in column "C". This value is taken from the first value I have in a drop down menu, set up on a sheet called "Lists" with the named range "RDStaff".

Could someone perhaps tell me please how I may go about changing the functionality, so that as soon as column "A" is populated with the date, the first value from my list i.e. "Select" is automatically populated in column "C"?

Many thanks and kind regards

Chris

Comment: `Rows(Target.Row).Range("C1").Value = "Select"` - Isn't that all you need?

Comment: Hi @mattboy, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I did try this, but the issue I have is that the user can't select a value from the drop down menu without it reverting back to "Select". Many thanks and kind regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not clear exactly which cell in column C is where your validation list is being used from, but if you add the code below into your with statement it should work, of course, adjusting to the appropriate drop-down cell.

`.Range("C1").Value = Sheets(1).Range("C10").Value`

Now, this assumes your drop down list, based on your validation is in the first sheet of your workbook (by index) in cell C10. You'll need to adjust these to match your data / workbook structure.

The point is that you don't hard code the value. You reference the value from the drop-down list location.

Per your comments, here is a code snippet to add the validation list into your code.

```
With Rows(Target.Row)

    '... your existing code
    With Range("C1").Validation
      .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:=xlBetween,  Formula1:=Lists!RDStaff ' you may need to make this named range global for it to work on another sheet in this context
      .IgnoreBlank = True
      .InCellDropdown = True
    End With

End WIth
```

Comment: Hi @Scott Holtzman, thank you for taking the time to reply to my post. I admit, I'm not really sure where to make the change. However, this is my fault as I didn't provide many details in my post. My initial post includes my full script. What I'm looking to do is when the 'Date' automatically populates the cell in column "A" starting from row7, I'd like the cell in column "C" to show the text value "Select". This value is the first value in a drop down menu set on a sheet called "Lists" with a named range of "RDStaff". I hope this helps. Many thanks and kind regards

Comment: @IRHM - you mean you want the whole drop-down validation to apply to column C? So the user can pick if they want ... But you want the word select to appear so they know the drop-down is there?

Comment: Hi @Scott Holtzman, thank you for coming back to me so quickly with this. My Input range is from rows 7:400. So for example if the user enters their name in cell "B7" I'd like the word "Select" to appear in "C7" with the user able to select the two other values from the drop down menu i.e. "Yes" or "No". The same would apply if the user enters their name in "B100", I'd like to have the word "Select" popluate cell "C100" etc. I hope this helps. Many thanks and kind regards.

Comment: @IRHM. Then you'll have to add the validation list to column C each time. You can surely google or macro record to get the syntax, but I put a snippet in my post for you.